# How to read xml node contains ":"

Tags: c#, xml

I have a xml file for example:

```
<item>
<name>John Caters</name>
<age>46</age>
<cd:creator>Wings Man</cd:creator>
</item>
```

And i use `(string)item.Element("name").Value` to get content between `<name>` and `</name>`

but, i don't know how to get beween  and

the're a problem width ":" in xml node

Comment: Are you using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` (a.k.a. LINQ-to-XML)?

Answer (score 4):

That shouldn't be the full XML file. There should be something specifying what the namespace alias "cd" actually means, e.g.

```
<doc xmlns:cd="http://something">
  <item>
    ..
    <cd:creator>...</cd:creator>
  </item>
</doc>
```

At that point it's easy:

```
XNamespace cd = "http://something";
string creator = (string) item.Element(cd + "creator");
```

... but you do need to know the namespace URL first.

Comment: @user2165201: It's `dc`, not `cd`, and the namespace is specified in the root element: `xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"`